# integrating java code with a browser

Tags: java, passwords, md5, sha1

This question is a general one.

I have java code for hmac(sha1 and md5) coding and a client server key exchange protocol(both codes in java).

**Now i want to embed/integrate this with a browser to implement password hashing. Any ideas how i might proceed about it?**

Answer (score 2):

[Java applets](http://java.sun.com/applets/) run in the browser.

But note that applets are a bit tedious to run, and you can have md5/sha1 with javascript.